# node_modules/segfault-handler: Command failed

Tags: node.js

Из-за чего возникает ошибка?
Обновил mac os до последней версии и еще Xcode.
  Теперь при запуске npm install в директории проекта возникает такая ошибка.

```
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/manking/inetpub/olap/svo/node_modules/ursa: Command failed.
Exit code: 127
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/manking/inetpub/olap/svo/node_modules/ursa
Output:
/Users/manking/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin/node-gyp: line 5: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js: No such file or directory"
info This module is OPTIONAL, you can safely ignore this error
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/manking/inetpub/olap/svo/node_modules/fsevents: Command failed.
Exit code: 127
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/manking/inetpub/olap/svo/node_modules/fsevents
Output:
/Users/manking/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin/node-gyp: line 5: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js: No such file or directory"
info This module is OPTIONAL, you can safely ignore this error
```

Comment: не видит директорию, переставь глобально нодку-то...вдруг сработает

Comment: Delete your $HOME/.node-gyp directory and try again.